# Flutter - Radio Button Wont Show Default Value that save at storage (SharedPreferences)

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to get default value for the radio button that stored in Storage (`SharedPreferences`).

**but the radio button wont pointing the saved value to the choice list**

below are my code :

`app_interface_widget.dart` :

```
class AppInterfaceDialogWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AppInterfaceDialogWidgetState createState() => _AppInterfaceDialogWidgetState();
}

class _AppInterfaceDialogWidgetState extends State<AppInterfaceDialogWidget> {

  String pickRadioValue;
  @override
    void initState() {
      setState(() {
        this.initRadio();
      });
      super.initState();
  }

  Future initRadio() async {
    pickRadioValue = await app.getPreferredLanguage();
  }

  @override
    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              pickRadioValue = "en";
              app.setNewLanguage("en");
            });
          },
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text("Language 1",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 20.0),),
              ),
              Radio(
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                groupValue: pickRadioValue,
                value: "en",
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    pickRadioValue = val;
                    app.setNewLanguage("$pickRadioValue");
                  });    
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              pickRadioValue = "id";
              app.setNewLanguage("id");
            });
          },
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[  
              Expanded(
                child: Text("Language 2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 20.0),),
              ),
              Radio(

                activeColor: Colors.green,
                groupValue: pickRadioValue,
                value: "id",
                onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      pickRadioValue = val;
                      app.setNewLanguage("$pickRadioValue");
                    });
                  } ,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`app.dart` :

```
class app {

  Future<Null> init([String language]) async {
    if (_locale == null){
      await setNewLanguage(language);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<String> getPreferredLanguage() async {
    return _getApplicationSavedInformation('app');
  }

  Future<String> _getApplicationSavedInformation(String name) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    return prefs.getString(_storageKey + name) ?? '';
  }

  Future setPreferredLanguage(String lang) async {
    return _setApplicationSavedInformation('app', lang);
  }

  get currentLanguage => getPreferredLanguage();
  get locale => _locale;

...
```

**Especially in this part** of `app_interface_widget.dart` :

```
...
String pickRadioValue;
  @override
    void initState() {
      setState(() {
        this.initRadio();
      });
      super.initState();
  }
  Future initRadio() async {
    pickRadioValue = await app.getPreferredLanguage();
    print ("DEBUG = "+pickRadioValue);
  }
...
```

i have print debug value (`pickRadioValue`) and it show correct result at console log, but it wont make no choice at all at Radio Button. but if i set `pickRadioValue = "en"` then my Radio button will show the saved value / pointing to the one of choice list....

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, we can execute `async function` in other wayby using `then()` like below :

```
String pickRadioValue;
  @override
    void initState() {
      setState(() {
        ads.getPreferredLanguage().then((result){
          setState(() {
            print (":: debug result >>>"+result.toString());
            pickRadioValue = result;
          });
        });
      });
      super.initState();
}
```

by using this code, my Radio Button Show default value that saved at `SharedPreferences`.